# What server settings can I change to allow me to save links to 3rd party CDNs via my browser?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, server, webserver

All of a sudden my hosting company has changed their server rules to block people saving links to 3rd party sites (like CDNs) via the browser.

I code my CMS in the browser and need to be able to alter header links, eg:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I have access to Cpanel and htaccess. Would anyone know of any settings I could implement to fix this issue?

Comment: What you have written makes no sense.  What do you mean by "my hosting company has changed their server rules to block people saving links to 3rd party sites"?   In the highly unlikely event your service provider is blocking this behaviour, change service providers ASAP and don't look back.

Comment: I mean the company I purchased the shared server space through. I'm guessing they have a rule set up to prevent anything being written to their database that contains links like the Bootstrap CDN link above.

Comment: If that is indeed the case, run a mile (change hosting providers ASAP). That said what you describe, while possible, is highly unlikely. If anything they would be using a reverse proxy of some sort to implement this - but why would they do something that stupid, expensive and complex for cPanel hosting?

Comment: I don't use cPanel, but do you have mod_security enabled? If so, what happens if you disable it? (https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/security/modsecurity/)

Comment: What do you mean "via your browser"?   Changing your site on a shared web host is usually done by uploading it via FTP or SCP.